# Why does the sheaf cohomology of the constant sheaf on $\mathbb{R}$ vanish?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Sorry if this is a very basic fact, but for some reason I am not able to solve it.

I am trying to prove for $X =\mathbb{R}$ that the sheaf cohomology groups $(i>0)$ of the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}_{X}$ vanish.

From what I gather online it has something to do with $\mathbb{R}$ being simply connected. I know it is even contractible and that these cohomology groups are isomorphic for homotopic spaces, but I am looking for an argument not using this homotopy argument.

I think I understand this sheaf, namely that $\mathbb{Z}_{X}(U) = \mathbb{Z}^{I}$ where I has cardinality equal to the number of connected components of $U$ and the restriction maps are just projections and diagonal maps. But somehow I can't seem to find a flasque/injective resolution or a sort of dimension shift argument. I can use excision and mayer-vietoris but I don't know if this helps.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you think of $\mathbb{Z}_X$ as the sheaf of locally constant functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_X(U)$ is the set of locally constant functions $U \to \mathbb{Z}$) then maybe a natural flasque sheaf to try as the first step in a resolution would be the sheaf of all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$.  Or maybe, just try looking at the long exact sequence induced by the natural injection $\mathbb{Z}_X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler yes, you mean its inbedding in the flasque sheaf of discontinuous functions, the problem I have is that their sheaf cokernel isn't very clear to me as I have to sheafify. Maybe their quotient presheaf is already a sheaf as it is simply connected?

Comment: This is probably an overkill, but you can also use the Cech to derived functor spectral sequence.

Comment: @loch I don't know and I haven't proved such a spectral sequence, thus I'd rather find an argument more elementary :)

Comment: @loch How do you use Cech to derived functor spectral sequence ? In fact I really doubt there is an easy and purely algebraic argument for this problem, but if you have on I would love to read it !

Comment: @Roland Ah sorry I'm not sure what I was thinking

Comment: At least for the $H^1$ case, a nice argument would come from the equivalence of $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$ with the isomorphism classes of $\mathbb{Z}$-torsors.  A proof that any $\mathbb{Z}$-torsor on $\mathbb{R}$ is trivial (equivalent to showing it has a global section) should be similar to the proof of the homotopy lifting theorem from algebraic topology.  (And then there's a similar characterization of $H^2$ in terms of equivalence classes of gerbes - I'm not sure off the top of my head how hard that argument would be.)

Comment: In fact, I think the presheaf quotient of discontinuous functions by locally constant functions will end up being already a sheaf, in this specific case of $\mathbb{R}$.  So, it would follow that the quotient is actually flasque itself, giving a flasque resolution of "cohomological dimension" 1 so $H^n(X, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ for $n \ge 2$, and also that the sequence of global sections is exact implying that $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call a sheaf on $\mathbb{R}$ *interval-flasque* if for every inclusion of open intervals $(a, b) \subseteq (a', b')$, the restriction map $\Gamma((a', b'), \mathscr{F}) \to \Gamma((a, b), \mathscr{F})$ is surjective.  (Here, we allow $a = -\infty$ and/or $b = \infty$ and similarly for $a', b'$.)  We then claim that any interval-flasque sheaf of abelian groups on $\mathbb{R}$ is acyclic in $\mathfrak{Ab}(\mathbb{R})$.  Since in particular, the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is clearly interval-flasque, that will imply the desired result.

The proof proceeds similarly to the proof for generally flasque sheaves.  Here I'll follow the outline of the facts that the proof from Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* uses:

- *If $0 \to \mathscr{F}' \to \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{F}'' \to 0$ is a short exact sequence, and $\mathscr{F}'$ is interval-flasque, then $0 \to \Gamma(U, \mathscr{F}') \to \Gamma(U, \mathscr{F}) \to \Gamma(U, \mathscr{F}'') \to 0$ is exact for every open interval $U$.*  Here, in using Zorn's Lemma to show there exists a maximal preimage of $x \in \Gamma(U, \mathscr{F}'')$, you will need to use the fact that the union of a chain of intervals is again an interval.  Then, in showing that a preimage on a strict subinterval can be extended (and therefore, a maximal preimage must be a section over the full larger interval), you will need to use the fact that a nonempty intersection of two intervals is an interval, and likewise for the union of two overlapping intervals.
- *If $0 \to \mathscr{F}' \to \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{F}'' \to 0$ is a short exact sequence, and $\mathscr{F}'$ and $\mathscr{F}$ are both interval-flasque, then so is $\mathscr{F}''$.*  Here, the proof is pretty much the same as for the generally flasque case: use the previous fact, along with the Snake Lemma on the obvious morphism between short exact sequences of abelian groups.
- *Any injective object of $\mathfrak{Ab}(\mathbb{R})$ is interval-flasque.*  Well, we know it's flasque, so in particular it's interval-flasque.

So now, the standard proof that flasque sheaves are acyclic will also work for interval-flasque sheaves, with just a global replacement of "flasque" with "interval-flasque" in the proof.  Note that we *do* need the fact here that $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty, \infty)$ is considered an open interval in the preceding facts.

---

Now, it might be interesting to see where this proof fails if you try to apply it on $S^1$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$.  In particular, what goes wrong if you try to replace "open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$" with "open arcs in $S^1$"?  What goes wrong if you try to fix this failure by restricting to open arcs of length less than $\pi$?

Comment: Very nice ! Did you read this proof somewhere or did you make it ?

Comment: @Roland As far as I recall, I came up with it independently.

Comment: Indeed very nice! I was also thinking about filtering out the useful open subsets as we only have to say something globally about R, but I didn't know how to. I don't know if I am supposed to answer the questions, but it goes wrong for S^{1} with taking intersections. Do you mean that when the arcs are restricted the global arc S^{1} (2 \pi) is not obtained via Zorn?

Comment: @DanielSchepler do you still think your previous idea still holds: the quotient presheaf of the sheaf of discontinuous functions and the constant sheaf on R is a flasque sheaf?

Comment: @Lilolance Yes, I believe so - more generally, the presheaf quotient of a flasque sheaf by an interval-flasque sheaf will be a flasque sheaf.  (The first fact above will apply to show the presheaf quotient coincides with the sheaf quotient on open intervals; and then any general open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a disjoint union of open intervals.)